# Does servlet engine read the whole request before calling a servlet?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, jetty

Servlet engine (e.g. `Tomcat` or `Jetty`) receives an HTTP request and calls a servlet with an `HttpServletRequest` object, which contains an `InputStream` of the request body.

Now I wonder if the engine has already read *the whole* request from the network and the `InputStream` is just a buffer in memory or it has read the request *partially* and when the servlet calls the `InputStream.read` it *actually* reads the socket.

Answer (score 1):

Usually that's not the case, because the request body can be really huge. A servlet container MAY do that if the content length is known and is small enough.

Answer (score 1):

It has to, at least in the case of POST, so it can form the requestParameterMap from the name-value pairs in the body of the request.

Comment: I doubt so. Does it really need to read the whole body to create that map ?

Answer (score 1):

you can read this article. [where does the HttpServeltInputStream read from — Zhihu](https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/p/601300961), this article is written by myself. It's written in Chinese, and if you don't read Chinese, here's a neat conclusion:

[image]

> picture source: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/http.html

you can also read some tomcat information from this question: [What is "Sim blocking" (seen in tomcat doc)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5495972/what-is-sim-blocking-seen-in-tomcat-doc)

Actually, in tomcat HttpServletRequest.getInputStream will read data from NIOChannel([NIOChannel source code in github](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/8.5.x/java/org/apache/tomcat/util/net/NioChannel.java)).

Although many buffer objects are used during the read. But these are still small buffers. Eventually it's a little bit of reading from the NIOChannel directly from the socket

[image]

- We read stream byte from `CoyoteInputStream` directly.
- It (`CoyoteInputStream`) copy or read byte stream from the `InputBuffer` ;
- `InputBuffer` read data from the low level request Object: `CoyoteRequest` (which class is: `org.apache.coyote.Request`)
- `CoyoteRequest` read data from `Http11InputBuffer` if we use Connector: `HTTP/1.1`
- `Http11InputBuffer` read data from `NIOSocketWrapper`
- `NIOSocketWrapper` read data from `NIOChannel`