# Does a servlet container wait for complete HTTP request to be received before it calls doPost?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

When does a servlet container calls the methods doPost / doGet? Does it wait to receive the complete request from the web client before it starts processing it. OR it invokes the methods (doPost or doGet), just after receiving the HTTP headers and the method (POST, GET etc) of the HTTP request is identified?

My question is quite the same to the one asked in the below link:
[Does servlet engine read the whole request before calling a servlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18561092/does-servlet-engine-read-the-whole-request-before-calling-a-servlet)

But in addition to that, assuming that the servlet container will invoke the method doPost / doGet immediately after identifying the HTTP method and the content-length, what happens if the web client terminates before the full HTTP request is sent to the webserver/servlet container. How will the servlet thread be aware that the request received is not complete.

Comment: This is not specified by the Servlet specification. Each Servlet container can choose to implement that behavior any way they want. Which Servlet container do you want to know about?

Comment: I will be interested in knowing it for Tomcat.

Comment: This is to answer my own question - How will the servlet thread be aware that the request received is not complete?

Comment: When the servlet container receives the HTTP headers, based on the HTTP headers received, it invokes doPost / doGet method. It doesn’t wait for the complete request (as indicated in the content-length) to be received. If the application developer has called getParameter or its variants, then at this point, this method waits till the complete request is received. If the web client goes off without sending the full request, then getParameter returns null. Application developer needs to handle this scenario explicitly.

Comment: My personal opinion is that, getParameter should have a way to tell that it is a network I/O error, rather than returning null. Even better to throw an exception.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

Well I don't think the full content is received, what you get is a stream which you can read the content from.

> How will the servlet thread be aware that the request received is not complete.

Well you have the content length, so that is how much the container will have to read from the stream when requested, and if the stream is unavailable for some reason the container will throw an exception. It is the same  if the client disconects after you received all the data; until you write back, you wont know that the client has disconected.